# ProfileForm that collects extra fields on User Signup

Tags: python, django

I have a `signupView` that shows 2 forms: `SignUpForm` and `ProfileForm`.

Basically, `SignUpForm` collects data like `first_name`, `last_name`, `user_name`, `email`, `password1`, `password2`.

And `ProfileForm` collects data like `dni`, `birthdate`, `shipping_address`, etc.

I'm using this approach because is what I know. But was wondering if I can collect the fields in `ProfileForm`  in just one form, the `SignUpForm`.

**views.py**

```
@transaction.atomic
def signupView(request):
    peru = Peru.objects.all()
    department_list = set()
    province_list = set()
    district_list = set()
    for p in peru:
        department_list.add(p.departamento)
    department_list = list(department_list)
    if len(department_list):
        province_list = set(Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0]).values_list("provincia", flat=True))
       province_list = list(province_list)
    else:
        province_list = set()
    if len(province_list):
        district_list = set(
        Peru.objects.filter(departamento=department_list[0], provincia=province_list[0]).values_list("distrito",
                                                                                                     flat=True))
    else:
        district_list = set()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, request.FILES) 

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name='Clientes')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
            raw_password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.refresh_from_db()  # This will load the Profile created by the Signal

            profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list, request.POST, request.FILES,
                                       instance=user.profile)  # Reload the profile form with the profile instance
            profile_form.full_clean()  # Manually clean the form this time. It is implicitly called by "is_valid()" method
            profile_form.save()  # Gracefully save the form

            return redirect('shop:email_confirmation_needed')

    else:

        user_form = SignUpForm()

        profile_form = ProfileForm(district_list, province_list, department_list)

    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

**models.py**

```
### User Profile ###

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='profile_pics/default_profile_pic_white.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name) + "'s profile"




@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "Las contraseñas no coinciden.",
    }

    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Nombre", max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Apellido', max_length=100, required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(label='Nombre de usuario', max_length=100, required=True,
                               error_messages={'invalid': "you custom error message"})
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Correo electrónico', max_length=60, required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmar contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1',
                  'password2')


class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    MONTHS = {
        1:'ene', 2:'feb', 3:'mar', 4:'abr',
        5:'may', 6:'jun', 7:'jul', 8:'ago',
        9:'set', 10:'oct', 11:'nov', 12:'dic'
    }

    def __init__(self, district_list, province_list, department_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['shipping_district'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Distrito', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in district_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_province'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Provincia', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in province_list]))
        self.fields['shipping_department'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Departamento', choices=tuple([(name, name) for name in department_list]))


    dni = forms.CharField(label='DNI', max_length=100, required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Celular')
    birthdate = forms.DateField(label='Fecha de nacimiento', widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2012), months=MONTHS))
    shipping_address1 = forms.CharField(label='Dirección de envío', max_length=100, required=True)
    shipping_address2 = forms.CharField(label='Referencia (opcional)', max_length=100, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('dni', 'phone_number', 'birthdate', 'shipping_address1',
                  'shipping_address2', 'shipping_department', 'shipping_province', 'shipping_district')
```